# Error while deploying thorntail generated package in java 11 runtime

Tags: java, jboss, thorntail

After switching to java 11, the package generated using the latest thorntail version throws an error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: some class from [Module \"org.hibernate.commons-annotations\" version 5.0.5.Final-redhat-00002 from BootModuleLoader@62408c4 for finders [JDK Module Finder, BootstrapClasspathModuleFinder, BootstrapModuleFinder(org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap), ClasspathModuleFinder, ContainerModuleFinder(swarm.container), ApplicationModuleFinder(thorntail.application), org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.modules.DynamicModuleFinder@75bedaca]]"}}
```

before that, it was working okay with java 8. adding multiple thorntail's hibernate fractions and the hibernate-commons-annotations jar to the package didn't help.

Comment: First of all, Thorntail has been long dead. The community project reached end of life more than 2 years ago, the Red Hat supported product more than a year ago. I strongly suggest you migrate to Quarkus or WildFly. That said, your question contains very little details that could be used to diagnose a possible problem. The error message even seems edited -- what's "some class"? Could you at least paste the full startup log of the application?

Comment: I know it's dead, but it's a legacy, and switching to other options is out of my hands. I can't share the full stack trace, but the class is an entity that was being found OK when we execute using java 8, but suddenly after migration to 11 we are getting this exception

Comment: Well if that redacted class is your entity class, then there's probably something horribly wrong in how class loading is set up, because the Hibernate Common Annotations module indeed is not supposed to see it. If migrating away from Thorntail is not an option right now, you can stay on Java 8 -- there are vendors who will release OpenJDK 8 updates for a few more years. Note that Thorntail and hence also the application is probably affected by multiple CVEs already, and it's only gonna get worse.